# Как сделать вывод без табуляции?

Tags: python-3.x

```
# Программа для вычисления положения мяча при вертикальном движении

v0 = 5       # Начальная скорость (м/с)
g = 9.80665  # Ускорение свободного падения (м/с^2)
t = 0.6      # Время (с)

y = v0*t - 1/2*g*t**2 # (м)

print ('Исходные данные:')
print ("Начальная скорость =             %6.5f м/c " % (v0))
print ("Ускорение свободного падения =   %6.5f м/c^2 " % (g))
print ("Время =                          %-6.5f c " % (t))
print ('Выходные данные:')
print ("Текущая высота положения мяча =  %6.5f м " % (y))

del v0, g, t, y
```

Программа все выводит ровно по строчкам. Вопрос можно ли это сделать без табуляции?

Comment: https://pyformat.info/

Answer (score 2):

Можно с помощью `prettytable` сделать таблички:

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable

t_in = PrettyTable()
t_out = PrettyTable()

t_in.field_names = ["Входные данные", "Значение"]
t_in.add_row(["Начальная скорость", "%6.5f м/c " % v0])
t_in.add_row(["Ускорение свободного падения", "%6.5f м/c^2 " % g])
t_in.add_row(["Время", "%-6.5f c " % t])

t_out.field_names = ["Выходные данные", "Значение"]
t_out.add_row(["Текущая высота положения мяча", "%6.5f м " % y])

t_in.align = "l"
t_out.align = "l"
print(t_in)
print(t_out)
```

Вывод:

```
+------------------------------+----------------+
| Входные данные               | Значение       |
+------------------------------+----------------+
| Начальная скорость           | 5.00000 м/c    |
| Ускорение свободного падения | 9.80665 м/c^2  |
| Время                        | 0.60000 c      |
+------------------------------+----------------+
+-------------------------------+------------+
| Выходные данные               | Значение   |
+-------------------------------+------------+
| Текущая высота положения мяча | 1.23480 м  |
+-------------------------------+------------+
```